# xsession choices not displayed (18.04)

Tags: 18.04, window-manager, .desktop, gdm, xmonad

I upgraded from 14.04 (! yikes) to 18.04 and can't seem to get the choices for my sessions to display when I log in. I copied over my old `.desktop` file:

```bsh
10:21:00 $ ls -l /usr/share/xsessions/*.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 323 May  2  2018 /usr/share/xsessions/ubuntu-communitheme-snap.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 247 May  2  2018 /usr/share/xsessions/ubuntu.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 217 Apr 16 10:12 /usr/share/xsessions/xmonad.desktop
```

but when I log out, or restart, I never see the little gear icon that I have been promised will present itself to choose which session to use. These are the contents of `{xmonad,ubuntu}.desktop`:

```
10:23:57 $ cat /usr/share/xsessions/xmonad.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=XMonad
Comment=Lightweight tiling window manager
Exec=/home/benwolfson/.xmonad/start-xmonad
# with or without the TryExec line, no dice
TryExec=/home/benwolfson/.xmonad/start-xmonad
Icon=custom_xmonad_badge.png
Type=XSession
10:24:05 $ cat /usr/share/xsessions/ubuntu.desktop 
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Ubuntu
Comment=This session logs you into Ubuntu
Exec=env GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE=ubuntu gnome-session --session=ubuntu
TryExec=gnome-shell
Type=Application
DesktopNames=ubuntu:GNOME
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=gnome-session-3.0
```

Even without my added `xmonad.desktop`, though, I would've expected to see at least two choices, since there were already two files!

I feel like I'm missing something extremely obvious here?

ETA: if I change the default display manager from `gdm3` to `lightdm`, I'm presented with two options: Ubuntu, and Ubuntu on Wayland. But not xmonad.

Comment: You could duplicate the working `ubuntu.desktop` file and only change the name to rule out problems with your xmonad session file. Wayland sessions are stored in `/use/share/waylandsessions/` and I think I remember there was a GDM3 setting to enable X sessions or force wayland, but I can't recall where.

Comment: I did do that. It is copied from my old root partition.

Comment: But that was 14.04 and lightdm. If you duplicate one of the new ones and change its name, and it is not listed as an alternative, then it's probably a problem with GDM3 or the current lightdm. If it does show up, there may have been changes you need to adapt your old files to.